# iOS : HMGLTransition Effects

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I would be grateful if someone help to implement the HMGLTransition effects

here is my code :

```
 [[HMGLTransitionManager sharedTransitionManager] setTransition:transition];
        Book2 *bookView = [[[Book2 alloc] init] autorelease];
        [[HMGLTransitionManager sharedTransitionManager] presentModalViewController:bookView onViewController:self];
        [bookView release];
```

I need goto another view with FlipTransition , but my app will be freezed !

is this api PRIVATE or PUBLIC ?

Answer (score 0):

[`HMGLTransitionManager`](https://github.com/Split82/HMGLTransitions/wiki/About/cbde86ba4bf5abb3aba42f65d89d040e298f97c7) is a 3rd party library.  It uses OpenGL to render its animations.

For a simple flip animation it might be best to use the standard apple stuff.  Try using the [modal's view flip](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal).